# Angular-material table pagination not working in IE 10

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I use angular-material's components in my angular(4.4.4) application . However , table's pagination (mat-paginatior) malfunctions . The next and prev buttons seems to be disabled . This issue is only in IE 10.

As per documentation , angular-material should support n-1 browsers which implies that IE 10 is also in the list . However it is evident that library does not work in it .

Is there any fix or a polyfill to make the component work properly in IE 10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you opened `polyfills.ts`and imported all IE10 lines that required to be uncommented, as well as `npm install --save classlist.js` and `web-animations-js`, and it still doesn't work then it's likely not compatible.

[The Angular Material 2 github notes the following](https://github.com/angular/material2)

> Browser and screen reader support
>
> Angular Material supports the most recent two versions of all major browsers: Chrome (including Android), Firefox, Safari (including iOS), and IE11 / Edge

IE11, and Edge (but not IE10 or less)

Comment: @lancovici I have already added those polyfills . I guess nothing can be done over this.

Answer (score 1):

Add this styles in global scss and paginator will work correctly :D

// IE 10

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  // bug with pagination in table
  .mat-button-focus-overlay, .mat-ripple.mat-button-ripple {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, as I see - the angular material not support --IE10, only IE11+.

[issue about it and answer](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7314)

[another issue and answer](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7836#issuecomment-337336292)